# model.evaluate on MNIST data produces TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have built a model on Tensorflow 2 (using Keras) to train and evaluate on MNIST data. It can properly run the commands:

```
model.prepare_training()

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, callbacks=[model.MS, model.WS])   

pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Yet, when I try to evaluate it against the test data using

```
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

I get a large error message specifically for the `model.evaluate` command, whose last part reads:

```
TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.
```

I have seen similar questions which were 'solved' by the OP updating their Tensorflow and/or Keras to the most recent version, but I've done that already and it didn't work. The model also works, since I've taken the prediction and found a rough estimate of the accuracy, which is 88%. So, the problem is probably not a logical one, but a technical one.

Any idea as to what might be happening?

**EDIT:**

As per request, here's how I load the data:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: please post the code where you initialize `x_test` and `y_test `

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(). Do you mean this?

Comment: post the entire code, makes no sense tu have an error like this

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the code is too big to post here, unfortunately. But if you have any ideas that require a part of it, I'd gladly post that

Comment: Update: I have since then figured out this was a bug with TensorFlow 2